# Will react destroy all old doms in component if state is changed?

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

I have a component has a list of items like this:

```
loadMore() {
    const len = this.state.itemList.length;
    if (len < 1000) {

        const newItems = Array.from({length:10}, (v,i) => "item-" + (i+len));
        this.setState({itemList: this.state.itemList.concat(newItems)});
    } else {
        alert("no more");
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <ul>
            this.state.itemList.map((item, i) => 
                <li key={i}>item</li>
            )
        </ul>
        <a onClick={this.loadMore.bind(this)}>Loading</a>
        </div>
    )
}
```

So, when I click `Loading`, **will react remove all old doms then recreate them?**

In fact, I am just adding elements, not replace them, so if react do this, the performance is not so good, **how can I avoid this?**

Comment: From my understanding, React will not destroy and recreate the elements as long as they are properly keyed. It will only add the new elements.

Comment: and using indexes as keys is not a good idea

Comment: @erdysson so what is the better choice?

Comment: it should be something which will be unique for each item even if they are not rendered. for example if you have a user list, then unique user ids are good choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question.

React will try to **reuse the DOM whenever possible**.

In your example you use `key` that will repeat in every loop because it’s index-based. It will go from 0 to n in every loop. **Whenever key repeats, the DOM will be reused and content updated.**

These two docs can help you learn more about it:

- [Reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html)
- [Dynamic Children](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the react docs:

> ReactDOM.render() controls the contents of the container node you pass
>   in. Any existing DOM elements inside are replaced when first called.
>   Later calls use React’s DOM diffing algorithm for efficient updates.
>
> ReactDOM.render() does not modify the container node (only modifies
>   the children of the container). In the future, it may be possible to
>   insert a component to an existing DOM node without overwriting the
>   existing children.

So its clear that react does not remove all old DOMs and recreate them rather renders a DOM based on the differences between the present and the previous DOM

In you case you are using key for the `<li>` components thus react will check for the keys and wherever it matches it keeps that part of the DOM and updates for the new entries.

**[Resource](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html)**

Answer (score 0):

When you change your **state** then it will call **render** method of the component. Then it will compare the new DOM created by render method and already rendered DOM of changed component only and will replace/add/remove only changed part using diffing algorithm.